# Continue series with index incremented as existing series

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple series with a time (ms) as index

how can repead the series by incrementing the index.

e.g

I have this

```
time_ms     ser1

10          1
20          0
30          0
40          1
50          0
60          0
```

and want have this

```
time_ms     ser1

10          1
20          0
30          0
40          1
50          0
60          0
70          1
80          0
90          0
100         1

.
.
.


1000        0
1010        1
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. Please post some code you have tried. We can try helping you but only after you have put in some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the dataframe using a `range`, and populate the `ser1` column with [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html), which will replicate the values in `df.ser1` to match the specified length:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1010
step = 10

(df.set_index('time_ms')
   .reindex(range(10, n, step))
   .assign(ser1=np.resize(df.ser1.values, (n-1)//step)).astype(np.uint8))

ser1
         time_ms      
10          1
20          0
30          0
40          1
50          0
60          0
70          1
80          0
90          0
100         1
110         0
120         0
130         1
140         0
150         0
...
```

Comment: unfortunatelly the assign is changing the dtype :(. I try to assign uint8. but after assign it is float again

Comment: updated it to use np.uint8. otherwise it did not work

Answer (score 0):

okay another approach to this problem (gives you more control)

```
##using np.arange, get the list

n = 1010 ##set the limit accordingly

time_ms = np.arange(df['time_ms'][0],(n+1)*df['time_ms'][0],10)
ser1 = ([1,0,0]*(len(a)//2))[:len(a)]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time_ms','ser1'])
df['ser1'] = ser1
df['time_ms'] = time_ms
```

---

```
      time_ms  ser1
0          10     1
1          20     0
2          30     0
3          40     1
4          50     0
5          60     0
6          70     1
7          80     0
8          90     0
9         100     1
10        110     0

...       ...   ...
```